# How to select debug profile in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 3 (*not* ASP) project in Visual Studio 2019 that has two different launch profiles:

[image]

But whenever I launch my project, it always uses the first profile, even if I have the second profile selected in my project settings. How do I tell Visual Studio to actually use the other launch profile?

**EDIT:** This is what my toolbar looks like:

[image]

I have no dropdown to select a launch configuration. I found the "Start Debug Target" command and can add that to my toolbar, but it doesn't have a dropdown either, it looks just like the regular start button.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In projects you can configure the profile, not select it.
In order to select a profile you should choose it from dropdown list next to start button:

[image]

***EDIT***

On my VS the button is called **Debug Target** and is placed under **Standard** section in toolbar.

However, there's something fishy about this button in visual studio. When I removed button from visual studio I couldn't find it among other commands to readd it. After some googling I even found out there were problems with this in past.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/323626/if-you-remove-debug-target-from-toolbar-you-can-ne.html

Ewentually I found out two ways to bring it back.

1. Reset the standard toolbar

[image]

2. Add it from Add or remove buttons section next to standard toolbar

[image]

Comment: I don't have a dropdown next to my start button. I'm guessing I just don't have the right button on my toolbar, but I can't seem to find it anywhere in the toolbar customization. Do you know what it's called and what category it's in?

Comment: On my VS the button is called Debug Target and is placed under Standard section in toolbar.

Comment: Your edit works for me, thanks! Indeed very strange.

Comment: "Debug Target" is actually a sub-menu with some complicated sub-sub-menus.